# Windows Installer 3.1

Tags: windows

We are shipping a product which has a dependency on .Net 4.0. THis essentially means that Any one below XP SP3 will not be able to use our product. Our product also has a dependency on Windows Installer 3.1. Now does Windows Installer 3.1 ship by default on XP SP3 onwards. Is there a way the user can downgrade from Windows Installer 3.1 on XP SP3 and above.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN article [Released Versions of Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371185.aspx) states that XP SP3 comes with Windows Installer 3.1.4001.5512 by default, though of course it can be updated as well to a later release. I'm not sure downgrading is possible to do easily, if at all. I don't think you need bother that a normal end user would have somehow downgraded the Windows Installer version that their OS came with.